# how to change storyboard based on language at runtime in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, localization, storyboard

To support localization I have made two Main.stroyboard, one for Persian and one for English (rather than just have .string file)
It acts good for different localization.

---

Now I want to have language options in my app, so user can change the language of app. For this I want to load correct storyboard based on user selection.
what i am using is as following:

```
        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "fa", ofType: "lproj")
        let bundle = Bundle(path: path!)

        let nsb = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: bundle)
        let vc = nsb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainController")
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Although it changes the Storyboard based on user selection but all the images are missing!

is there any reason for that?
is my method statndard?

Comment: you have to create one common story board that in you have one controller  that give option for select language after language select you push your controller to particular viewcontroller .

Comment: Why do you need two storyboards? You can use one and you can change the content according to user selection

Comment: @Sivagami because It was easier to change contents like, strings, images and fonts with another storyboard!

Comment: "is my method statndard?"  No, it's not.  Suppose that one has an app supporting 30 different languages.  Should he or she localize each storyboard for all those languages?  If your answer is yes, then be my guest.

Comment: One thing you don't make clear (to many readers) in your question is that you are working with a right to left language vs. left to right. I can see how you might create a left to right storyboard and a right to left. One as well.  I don't have your answer however.

Comment: @ElTomato 1: so what is the purpose of having different storyboard for different languages !? 2: alternative solution is having 30 different strings, fonts, images and so on and assign them to every string or images at runtime. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can change it at runtime:

define a new bundle class:

```
 var bundleKey: UInt8 = 0

class AnyLanguageBundle: Bundle {

override func localizedString(forKey key: String,
                              value: String?,
                              table tableName: String?) -> String {
    
    guard let path = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &bundleKey) as? String,
          let bundle = Bundle(path: path) else {
        return super.localizedString(forKey: key, value: value, table: tableName)
    }
    
    return bundle.localizedString(forKey: key, value: value, table: tableName)
}
}
```

and then extend Bundle class like this:

```
extension Bundle {

class func setLanguage(_ language: String) {
    defer {
        object_setClass(Bundle.main, AnyLanguageBundle.self)
    }
    objc_setAssociatedObject(Bundle.main, &bundleKey, Bundle.main.path(forResource: language, ofType: "lproj"), .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
}
}
```

and finally for change language at runtime use this:

```
Bundle.setLanguage("tr")
Bundle.setLanguage("en")..
```

when you change the language you should reload your view controller by instantiating again your viewcontroller from its storyboard because we changed our bundle.

Comment: how to `reload view controller by instantiating again`.. could you tell me.. I am following your process

Comment: after Bundle.setLanguage("")  every new view controller follows the localization by this code if you want we can have meeting for this email me: Jamalzare514@gmail.com